# cakePHP findAllBy not working for mulitple items?

Tags: cakephp, search

I am using cakePHP version 2.3.7 and would like to find All properties with a ref beginning with the 2 first characters, for example AB. But, the function findAllBy will only work if I enter the full reference number, it doesn't seems to accept only the first 2 characters to find all.

Am I doing something wrong? Cookbook says: findAllBy(string $value, array $fields, array $order, int $limit, int $page, int $recursive) which works as a find[All]

My search form

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Property',array('action'=>'mysearch'));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('ref', array('label' => 'Reference:')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Search'); ?>
```

The search function in the controller.

```
    public function mysearch() {
            $ref = $this->data['Property']['ref'];
            $this->Property->recursive = 0;
    $propData = ($this->Property->findAllByRef($ref));
            $this->set('property', $propData);
            debug ($propData);
}
```

I know it works if I type the correct reference number, but I would like to findAllByRef beginning with the first 2 or more characters only, like a sort of AB* filter.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### findAllBy is an alias

> would like to find All properties with a ref beginning with the 2 first characters

The magic find functions `findAllByXXX` are just an alias for:

```
find('all', array('conditions' => array('xxx' => 'param'));
```

As such it's unsuitable for the objective, and the behavior matches exactly the observation (only works if the full reference is passed).

### Use the right function

What's described in the question is a simple like query:

```
$propData = $this->Property->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'ref LIKE' => $ref . '%'
    )
));
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much. I think I totaly misunderstood this magic find all by.